# How do i get an url address stored in a plist and pass it through a segue to a uiwebview

Tags: ios, url, uiwebview, plist

I am using the following code to get a value for an url address from my plist and passing it through segue to my uiwebview.
Unfortunately it is not working as i had hoped, so can someone please advise what the problem is
many thanks

the plist contains the url address as a string e.g http://www.apple.com

this is the prepare for segue

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    NSString *abc = [NSString stringWithString:[[currentValues    objectAtIndex:0]objectForKey:@"Web"]];
    myWebView  = [segue destinationViewController];
    myWebView.url = abc;
}
```

this is the view did load on my modal view controller containing the uiwebview

```
NSURL *urlToLoad = [NSURL URLWithString:self.url];
[self.webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:urlToLoad]];
[super viewDidLoad];
```

Comment: I don't think UIWebView has a property name .url, I could be wrong though. Other than that your code looks correct. Put in some NSLog calls to print out the value of abc, and .url after the segue, then see what they contain.

Comment: You can store the URL in the plist using string property and while retrying plz try to print and see if you are able to ge the correct url string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for all the input, but i finally sussed it out by refactoring my code slightly 
it now works as expected using the following

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
   // NSString *abc = [NSString stringWithString:[[currentValues objectAtIndex:0]objectForKey:@"Web"]];
    myWebView  = [segue destinationViewController];
    myWebView.url = [NSString stringWithString:[[currentValues objectAtIndex:0]objectForKey:@"Web"]];
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The destination view controller is contained in a Navigation Controller if it is presented modally.  So you need to do something like

```
UINavigationController *nav  = (UINavigationController *)[segue destinationViewController];
 myWebView  = [[nav viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];
```